# Windows 10 screen flicker only on certain apps / when full screened?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, vmware

I just received a 2016 Razer Blade (gtx 1060, FHD display) and have had issues with some apps (Chrome and VMware Workstation) causing rapid screen flickering when full screened. Additionally, some components of windows such as Explorer, the power options screen, etc also cause flickering but only when the window is made fullscreen.

No other games or applications aside from the ones mentioned above cause flickering (regardless if they are running full screen).

I have tried:

- Disabling hardware acceleration in chrome and VMware
- Updating to the latest GPU drivers from Nvidia
- Doing a clean install of the GPU drivers on the razer support website
- Making sure all of my windows updates are installed
- Doing a clean install of windows
- Disabling microsoft services like error reporting as described here
  (http://techdows.com/2015/08/fix-screen-flashing-issue-in-windows-10.html)
- Uninstalling dropbox
- Making sure not to have programs that are known to cause flicker in
  windows 10 (Norton, IDT audio, etc)
- Switching M.2 SSDs
- Plugging in an external monitor (PROBLEM ONLY HAPPENS ON INTERNAL
  LAPTOP DISPLAY)
- Settings Vsync "on" in nvidia settings
- Setting the Nvidia GPU to be the active GPU
- Setting the Intel GPU to be the active GPU
- Booting into safe mode (still have flickering when windows like explorer are made fullscreen)
- Turning off smooth scroll

All of this to no avail. Does anyone have an idea what could be the common link between these applications and how to solve this?

Is a component of windows responsible for all of this?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem

Comment: Wouldn't a hardware problem affect most / all applications?

Comment: No it wouldn't.  Both apps you mention are OpenGL applications

Comment: So it sounds like a software problem then. I.e. - Graphics drivers / windows bug / application bug

Comment: You have confirmed, through your actions, its not caused by software.

Comment: mpv also have similar flickering on Windows 10, but not on Windows 7.